# Getting ValueError when trying to obtain confusion matrix of trained CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, confusion-matrix

I had a classification problem in which I trained a CNN and now I was hoping I could obtain its confusion matrix. I tried the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
#Generate the confusion matrix
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

print(cf_matrix)
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and continuous-multioutput targets
```

`x_test` is made of `(84, 32, 32)` - 84 monochrome images of shape 32x32

Is there a way around this problem?

Addendum: Model Summary (note: the output activation fn is softmax)
[image]

Comment: Please post your model as well

Comment: Included in addendum

Comment: i think you just need to extract the class from the softmax output (i.e `y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, 0)` and pass that to the confusion matrix

Comment: when I do that `y_pred` now has shape `(7,)` but `y_test` has shape `(84,1)`

Comment: I'm sorry! Typo, I meant: `y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)`,

Comment: You are correct, unfortunately I am still getting the same `ValueError` as before though. I checked the shape of the arrays and they are both equal in size and also their content provides the class of each image so I do not know why I still cannot obtain the confusion matrix.

Comment: Could be that `y_pred` appears to be  `dtype=int64` and `y_test` is `dtype=object`

Comment: How does `y_test` look? What does `np.unique(y_test)` output? Becuase scikit-learn is saying `y_test` has `unknown` targets referring to `y_test`

Comment: That was the problem, I converted `y_test` to `int64` and that did the job. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to sum it up from the comments, there were two problems:

1. `confusion_matrix` expects the class labels and not the logits output from the Dense layer with softmax activation. This is fixed simply by doing:

`y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)`

2. `y_true` is identified as having targets of `unknown` type (see the error). Hence, make sure it has the correct type of data (i.e., the true class labels).